# YADCF plugin not loading with DataTables 1.10.7

Tags: jquery, datatable, yadcf

As per the title, I have an html table which I am formatting using the jQuery DataTables plugin. I am also using the YADCF plugin to generate individual column sorting functionality.

The problem is I cannot get any of the search functions to appear in my table header (nor in the footer). I'm trying to get a text search field below each column in the table.

I am using DataTables v1.10.7 with YADCF v0.8.7 and jQuery 1.10.2.

I have included the YADCF css and script files in my html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/yadcf/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css" />
<script src="lib/yadcf/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js" ></script>
```

They are both loading as I checked the source of my webpage and they are visible there.

My table has the following html configuration:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
            <td>Column 5</td>
            <td>Column 6</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
            <td>Column 5</td>
            <td>Column 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

My JavaScript configuration looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(initTable);

function initTable() {
    var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "ajax": {
              // config for data going to the server
              "url": "/loadTable",
              "method": "POST",
              "data": function (data) {
                  return JSON.stringify(data);
              },

              // config for data coming back from the server
              "dataType": "json",
              "dataSrc": function (json) {
                  var jsObj = $.parseJSON(json);
                  return jsObj.data;
              }
          },
          "columns": [
              {
                  "name": "name1",
                  "data": "key_column1",
                  "defaultContent": "(no data)"
              },
              {
                  "name": "name2",
                  "data": "key_column2",
                  "defaultContent": "(no data)"
              },
              {
                  "name": "name3",
                  "data": "key_column3",
                  "defaultContent": "(no data)"
              },
              {
                  "name": "name4",
                  "data": "key_column 4",
                  "defaultContent": "(no data)"
              },
              {
                  "name": "name5",
                  "data": "key_column5",
                  "defaultContent": "(no data)"
              },
              {
                  "name": "name6",
                  "data": "key_column6",
                  "defaultContent": "(no data)"
              }
          ],
          "dom": '<f><lip><rt><ip>',
          "language": {
              "search": "Search:"
          },
          "pagingType": "full_numbers"
      });
    yadcf.init(myTable, [{
              column_number: 0,
              filter_type: "text"
          }, {
              column_number: 1,
              filter_type: "text"
          }, {
              column_number: 2,
              filter_type: "text"
          }, {
              column_number: 3,
              filter_type: "date"
          }, {
              column_number: 4,
              filter_type: "text"
          }, {
              column_number: 5,
              filter_type: "text"
          }]);
  }
 }
```

As far as I can tell I am calling the init function correctly on my DataTable, but absolutely nothing happens when I include the init() call. I don't get any errors, and there are no errors in the FireBug console.

I have read other posts where people have actually received an error, possibly because they were using an old version of DataTables with the new init() function, or vice versa, but that's not the case for me.

I even debugged the source file for YADCF and I can see the code getting called that creates the elements to be added to the table header, but for some reason I never see anything in the table itself.

The server-side config should be irrelevant in this instance as it only provides the data for the table, and has nothing to do with the visual configuration of the table. So I don't think the issue is there.

Please help.

Comment: can you provide a link to your test case?

Comment: Well, I tried creating one on [link](http://live.datatables.net/), but I can't find a way to import the YADCF JS and CSS files. As far as I know there isn't a link to a CDN containing them, so I can't actually call the yacdf init() function without receiving an error.

Comment: you can use https://rawgit.com/ for instant cdn , here a bit modified jsbin of your sample http://live.datatables.net/papuvuqi/1/edit (yadcf works perfect)

Comment: Thanks for that. After pasting the html for my table into the live editor the column filters stopped showing. I noticed that my `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` tags had `<td>` tags for each column header, rather than `<th>` tags. It makes sense now, since I suspect YADCF was looking for the `<th>` tag to add the filter to, and it couldn't.

Lesson learnt: check that your HTML is valid before anything else.
All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use init event of Datatable :

```
myTable.on( 'init.dt', function () {
        yadcf.init(myTable, [{...}]);
});
```

this will force yadcf to wait for the end of DataTable init before initialising itself